# JavaScript function not working on front page?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I have a modal window for the contact form with a link on the sidebar of [my site](http://www.bintley.com):

```
<a href="/contact-us/"  onClick="openDialog();return false;" style="color:#e40"><strong>Click to contact us</strong></a>
```

While it works perfectly on every other pages, it doesn't work on the [home page](http://www.bintley.com). Try clicking it and it won't open the modal window.

The function openDialog() is defined in global.js:

```
function openDialog() {
    jQuery("a#inline").trigger('click')
}
```

I don't know why. And I don't know how to debug JavaScript. It has no errors displayed whatsoever. Can you help me debug this and also let me know how I can debug it myself in future?

Thanks!

Comment: check your console, maybe have some conflict

Comment: there is no `a#inline` on the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that you are using a kind of wordpress plugin named like "modal dialog". It seems like this plugin not well install on your home page but other pages, so check the plugin setup of all the layouts include the one used by home page.

Comment: Turns out it's an option in the configurations of the plugin to display on the homepage.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <a id="contactLink" href="/contact-us/" style="color:#e40" > <strong> Click to contact us </strong> </a>
```

**Inside your script file:**

```
 var contactlink = document.getElementById('contactLink')
 contactLink.onclick = openDialog;
```

Would be a lot easier to debug if you didn't have CSS & Javascript mixed in with your markup. Separating everything (at least during production) is a good practice.

Get the Firebug Addon for FireFox. That's a good tool for debugging javascript. Also, you can hit F12 in your browser and the native development tools will come up.